# Why is BootStrap 4 Progress Bar Not Animating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking at the documenation on http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/progress/

It does not work there, and it does not work on the site I am building.

Has anyone else encountered this or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

[animated]='true' enabled the progress bar animation. Inspecting the progress bar you can see progress-bar-animated css class with below css code

```
animation: 1s linear infinite progress-bar-stripes;
```

You can simply add the above line and check.

Ex. progress bar sample

```
<p><ngb-progressbar type="warning" [value]="75" [striped]="true" [animated]="true"><i>50%</i></ngb-progressbar></p>
```

Inspecting this you will get

```
<div aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%;"><!----><i _ngcontent-c2="">50%</i></div>
```

The latest documents available with below link : 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar/examples

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an open issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17148

As a workaround, someone has suggested animating it manually like so:

```
$("#progressbar")
  .animate({
    "width": data["percent"]+"%"
  }, {
    duration: 600,
    easing: 'linear'
  });
```